# AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h:88:10: - ios

Tags: ios, warnings, afnetworking, afhttpclient

```
In file included from /Users/project/API.m:9:
In file included from /Users/project/API.h:9:
/Users/project/../AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h:88:10: warning: MobileCoreServices framework not found in project, or not included in precompiled header. Automatic MIME type detection when uploading files in multipart requests will not be available. [-W#warnings]
#warning MobileCoreServices framework not found in project, or not included in precompiled header. Automatic MIME type detection when uploading files in multipart requests will not be available.
```

- any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Umm...have you added MobileCoreServices?

Comment: What do you mean by adding MobileCoreServices?
I am newbie on IOS sorry, Where should I add?

Answer (score 1):

click on project name from left pane -> on right hand select summary -> click "+" button -> add "MobileCoresServices.Framework"

Save it

clean it

run it

Comment: I added already but the warning still persist. Please take a look on the image below.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6gbfe9ycz7u49l/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-28%20at%201.51.15%20PM.png

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Follow answer above to link agains the MobileCoreServices framework. You've done that, as per your screenshot

Step 2 - Include the following lines in your PCH (Precompiled Header) file. This file should be called PROJECTNAME-Prefix.PCH

```
 #import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
 #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

Then you should be good to go!